# JavaScript change format of a string, moving negative sign from the end to the front

Tags: javascript, string, string-formatting

I'm trying to format an output string from SAP, where they have negative sign placed at the end of the string.

e.g `999.99-`

How can I use JavaScript or Groovy to adjusted this so that the negative numbers are formatted correctly? They should be `-999.99` not `999.99-`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a regular expression:

```js
alert(('999.99-').replace(/([\d\.]*)-/, '-$1'))
```

Comment: @RickHitchcock Hitchcock  Updated to handle floating point numbers

Comment: I know the REGX will work, but our application only can take javascript or groovy. Do you guys know how to get that done with javascript or groovy?

Comment: @James That is javascript

Comment: replace(/([\d\.]*)(-?)/, '$2$1')) handles both positive and negative numbers

Comment: @loteq, it handles positive numbers fine as-is.  Nothing will be replaced in that instance.